# How can I filter a very large queryset (10 milions of records) based on two of its fields?

Tags: python, django, django-models, filter, django-queryset

I'm having this problem where I need to filter based on a condition a Django Queryset obtains a list of 10 million records and then I need to filter each one of them based on the values of two of their fields.

These are the two steps:

1. Filtering all the Model instances getting the one with a specific dataset_id
   `polygons = Polygon.objects.filter(Q(dataset_id=dataset_id))`;
2. Once I got the instances that met this filter, generally they are like 10 million records, filter each one of them to see if there's a point that is inside a polygon and now I do it like this:
   `all_points_poly = list(filter(lambda pol: shapely_polygon.contains(Point(pol.latitude,pol.longitude)), list(polygons)))`

This is the Polygon's model:

```
class Polygon(models.Model):
    pol_vertices_str = models.CharField(max_length=500,default="",null=True) 
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    value_0 = models.FloatField(default=None,null=True)
    dataset_id = models.ForeignKey(Node,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_value = models.CharField(max_length=500,default="",null=True)
    latitude = models.FloatField(default=0,null=True)
    longitude = models.FloatField(default=0,null=True)
    parametro_agg = models.CharField(max_length=500,default="",null=True)
    objects = models.Manager()
    copy_manager = CopyManager()
```

It takes like 13 minutes to do this stuff! Is there a way to do it in a more efficient way? I'm surprised by the fact that I'm getting these data from the DB and it's all so slow because I have done everything to save all the data in the DB to make all this stuff quicker but nothing has changed!

I have tried to do polygons.iterator(chunk_size=10000) but is slow the same and it does not resolve anything!

Comment: Share your models and relevant models

Comment: I added the model of the polygon that is the one related to the problem.

Comment: I have no experience with coordinates etc. but maybe [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/) (if you use Postgresql) is worth a look to handle that load in the database. [Django PostGIS docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/gis/install/postgis/)

Comment: There's no way to, extrapolate all the polygons that have that dataset_id field and then on them filter the ones that are inside the polygon, extrapolating their two fields latitude and longitude?

Comment: The slowest part of your code is not pulling data from the database. Make proper benchark of each part. My guess is that `list(polygons)` is slow and `shapely_polygon.contains(Point(pol.latitude,pol.longitude))` is even slower . Also it's unnecessary to convert polygons to list in `filter` method. You can use `Queryset` directly since it's iterable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try as soon as possible to not convert the polygons to a list and filter the Queryset directly but how can I check if the point is inside the polygon without calling the shapely_polygon.contains function?

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

At the end I have found a solution to this kind of problem:

1. I have added PostGIS extension, as Marco suggested; this way I can save in the database not latitude and longitude as two different FloatField, but as only one field that is PointField (it was a nightmare installing it in the dockerfile but I did it, change postgres image to postgis in docker-compose.yml, add django.contrib.gis to INSTALLED_APPS and change DB engine to postgis). This is the new Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9

# Add unstable repo to allow us to access latest GDAL builds
# Existing binutils causes a dependency conflict, correct version will be installed when GDAL gets intalled

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

RUN mkdir /code

WORKDIR /code

RUN echo deb http://deb.debian.org/debian testing main contrib non-free >> /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get remove -y binutils && \
    apt-get autoremove -y

# Install GDAL dependencies
RUN apt-get install -y libgdal-dev g++ --no-install-recommends && \
    pip install pipenv && \
    pip install whitenoise && \
    pip install gunicorn && \
    apt-get clean -y

# Install PostGIS
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y postgis postgresql-13-postgis-3-scripts && \
    apt-get clean -y

# Update C env vars so compiler can find gdal
ENV CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal
ENV C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal

ENV LC_ALL="C.UTF-8"
ENV LC_CTYPE="C.UTF-8"

COPY . /code

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

2. Add in the filter function the other condition that filters all the points that are inside the polygon selected (`coordinate__within(polygon)`), in this way it filters all the points of the dataset that are inside the polygon chosen in 0.2 seconds.

If you have some kind of problems with the installation of PostGIS in your project, feel free to ask, because I've spent a lot of days with this thing and I've seen everything!